# How to create modal asp.net form?

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to use a standard asp.net form in a modal?

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Create Account</h5>
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
        <form method="post" asp-controller="Accounts" asp-action="Edit">

            <label asp-for "Email">Email</label>
            <input asp-for="Email" type="email">
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span> 

            //...

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What problems are you having? And what do you mean by _ standard asp.net form_?

Comment: the problem is the modal closes! I dont know how else to fix that, except change type to button and do a http post via javascript (i.e not using asp.net form)

Comment: Is the modal closed automatically? Obviously you can put a form into a modal div, just ensure that the form is not nested inside other form.

Comment: If your submitting the form, you are leaving the page - what are you expecting?

Comment: Submitting the form will cause the app to navigate away from that page and expect a new page in the response from the server. If you want to keep the form open and wait for the response you'll need to use javascript/ajax to handle the submit/response.

Comment: Is it possible to use asp-validation with JavaScript / http post?

Comment: For validation,you could refer to the link adout Unobtrusive Client Side Validation in ASP.NET Core :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#client-side-validation